# How to output a list of all values in a specified column in a grouped object

Tags: python, list, pandas, group-by

I have the following problem: I have a grouped object. For each grouped object, I want to make a comma separated list of all the values contained in a specific column of that group. My Code is as follows:

```
for key, group in df.groupby('Column1'):
    All_values_in_group = []
    for item, frame in group['Column2'].iteritems():
        list = frame.split(',')
        for value in list:
            All_values_in_group.append(value)
            print key
            print All_values_in_group
```

The thought behind this is that I group my data by a specific column, and make an empty list. Then, for each `frame` (row) I make a list through splitting the `string` contained in the row at `','`. Each value in this list is then appended to my desired output_list `All_values_in_group`. This list shall be a 'summary' of all the data contained in Column2 for each row of group X.

My problem now is that I do not get one list, but several list when I `print` `All_values_in_group`, like this (L1 is the group key):

```
L1
['string1]
L1
['string1, 'string2']
L1
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

I only want one list for All_values_in_group containing all the values from Column2 in that group, much like the last row in the example, and I want to keep duplicates.

To make it clearer, here is an example of my data:

```
   Column1  Column2 
0     L1    string1,string2,string3
1     L1    string1
2     L1    string2,string3
3     L2    stringA,stringB
```

What I want is:

```
L1
All_values_in_group ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3']
L2
All_values_in_group ['stringA', 'stringB']
```

Does anybody know a way to make my code work like this? I have the feeling it's just something small, but I do not come around to it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby on 'Column1' and `apply` a lambda that calls `join` to concatenate all the string values and then if you desire construct a list object from that result:

```
In [22]:
df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply(lambda x: [','.join(x)])

Out[22]:
Column1
L1    [string1,string2,string3,string1,string2,string3]
L2                                    [stringA,stringB]
Name: Column2, dtype: object
```

Comment: wait, actually it doesn't work perfect. Each last and first string of a list are not comma separated, but joined together as one string...How can I correct that?

Comment: Hey, I have a question on the output if you don't mind. I am unsure on how to continue my work with that form of output. how could I for example count the occurences of each value for each group in the Data? I tried calling `count_values()` on the resulting object, but always get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'count_values'`.

Comment: Well storing lists in a df is not a good use of dataframes for many reasons such as this, you'd have to either perform the counting yourself of convert each row into a pandas Series and then you can use `value_counts`

Comment: or how would the lambda x function look if I wrote it as function? I just tried `def listi(x):
    lambda x: (',').join(x)`, but applying that causes the output to be empty..

Comment: You could do it like this: `In [83]:

df1 = df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply(lambda x: [','.join(x)])
df1 = df1.reset_index()
def func(x):
    print(pd.Series(x[0][0].split(',')).value_counts())
df1[['Column2']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
string1    2
string3    2
string2    2
dtype: int64
stringB    1
stringA    1
dtype: int64`

Comment: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`..Is there a way I could just get the last list created for a group and store it in a variable? That would maybe make it easier

Comment: not sure why you get the error, note that I'm using a double subscript `[[]]` to create a single column df when calling `apply`. You could iterate over each row for that column after the groupby so just take the result of my answer and iterate over 'Column2'